# Tensorflow ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working on a convolution neural network that measures several metrics. Originally it just included accuracy, and worked very well:

```
def convNeuralNet(train_images, train_labels, test_images, test_labels):
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 1)))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    
    images = np.expand_dims(train_images, axis = -1)
    test_images = np.expand_dims(test_images, axis = -1)
    
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    hisotry = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
    
    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, verbose=2)
    return test_acc
```

However, I am now working on adding in precision and recall metrics to those inside model.compile() and get an error.

```
def convNeuralNet(train_images, train_labels, test_images, test_labels):
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 1)))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    
    images = np.expand_dims(train_images, axis = -1)
    test_images = np.expand_dims(test_images, axis = -1)
    
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])

    hisotry = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
    
    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, verbose=2)
    return test_acc
```

Here is the error I am receiving and where it occurs in the code:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

```
---> 20 hisotry = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), batch_size = 128)
```

I was expecting the program to output the code to run as previously believed but record multiple metrics during execution rather than just accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide info about data so I can't tell for sure, but I think the error you are seeing is because of the mismatch between the shape of the model's output and the shape of the labels. The error is not due to the added precision and recall metrics but is related to how you are preparing your labels and the type of loss you are using.

When you use sparse_categorical_crossentropy as your loss, Keras expects labels to be in the format (batch_size, 1), which means each label is an integer indicating the class index. The model's output, in this case, should be of shape (batch_size, num_classes). If the output shape of the model and the shape of the labels match these criteria, there should not be an error.

Solution: add a [Lambda](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) layer so you can directly output the class value and you can have an output of (none,1) for a label (none,1).

```
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.argmax(x, axis=-1)))
```

Edit: In the last layer you have to neurons, that means 2 classes, so, if you don't have more classes you che transform the problem into a binary classification. To do that I suggest you do reduce the last dense layer from 2 neurons to 1, change the activation function into "sigmoid" and change also the loss function in "binary_cross_entropy". In this case you can avoid the lambda layer.